# Resize WPF label after updating content

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some labels which I update in code behind. The problem is that the label doesn't resize when I update the content of the label (it should resize to fit the content). I tried re-setting the label width to auto with Double.NaN in code behind as suggested in online resources I found but this doesn't seem to work.
The content is too long for the label when I update it in code even if I re-set the width to auto in code behind

My XAML label has Width defined as Width="Auto".
`<Label x:Name="wp7" Content="wp7" Grid.Column="2" Width="Auto" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83,386.03,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="1.065,-0.256"`>

The code behind relevant to this is as follows:

```
Label lb = (Label)FindName(bezetting.Key);
                if (lb != null)
                {
                    lb.Content = bezetting.Value;
                    lb.Width = Double.NaN;
                }
```

Why doesn't this work? Is it because the width is set to auto according to the original value that was set in XAML and not resized upon updating the label? How can I get it to do so?

Comment: Is the content of the Label being truncated? That's probably becasue there is no space left for the Label to grow. Please your XAML along with an image of what you are seeing if you want anyone to be able to help you out here.

Comment: Yes the content is being truncated. I can't figure out how to post an image if it is not online available, but I updated the question with the XAML. There should be enough space for the label to grow within the Grid column

Comment: Try to remove the RenderTransformOrigin and Margin. And how is the Grid defined?

Comment: Thanks, Removing RenderTransformOrigin did work, the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `RenderTransformOrigin` and `Margin` attributes that the designer (?) has added to your `Label`:

```
<Label x:Name="wp7" Content="wp7" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

There is no reason to explicitly set the `Width` property of a `Label` if you want it to resize itself based on the content.